# Excluding boost signal calling

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-signals

There is a signal and several objects with slots. I want to implement the behavior when one object calls signal and blocks its own connection. I guess a small snippet will be more informative:

```
typedef boost::signal<void()> TSignal;

template<class TSignal>
class SlotObject
{
public:

    void Connect(boost::shared_ptr<TSignal> pSignal, boost::function slot)
    {
        m_connection = pSignal->connect(slot);
        m_pSignal = pSignal;
    }

    // How to define TSignal signature here?
    VOID Call()
    {
        m_connection.block();
        (*m_pSignal)();
        m_connection.unblock();
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<TSignal> m_pSignal;
    boost::signals::connection m_connection;
};
```

The questions:

1. Is there a standard approach with some boost stuff? Do I reinventing the wheel?
2. How to define Call method with TSignal signature?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. In your example, the connection is owned by SlotObject, so the only use case I see for block()-ing it in Call() would be to break recursion, i.e., that slot() calls SlotObject::Call(). Is that the case?

Comment: I’m trying to synchronize adding items operation between several objects.  Each object can add items and it must send notifications to all others.  I.e. slot is not Call().  Call() is needed to send notifications to all object except owner.  I known it can be implemented through easier ways, just wondering about syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question: I'm not aware of a "standard boost way" to achieve what you want. You may post your question to the [boost users mailing list](http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html#users).

For your second question: Without varidic templates and rvalue references, forwarding is always cumbersome.

A few suggestions, in no particular order:

**1)** You may look at the boost/signal.hpp and the files in boost/signals/ to get an idea of how this kind of stuff can be done with the preprocessor, but here's a partial implementation to show the idea(warning: untested):

```
template<size_t Arity, class SignalT>
struct SlotBase;

template<class SignalT>
struct SlotBase<0, SignalT>
{
    typedef SignalT::slot_function_type SlotType;

    SlotBase(boost::shared_ptr<SignalT> S, SlotType F)
        : m_Signal(S), m_Connection(S->connect(F))){};

    void operator()()const
    {
        m_Connection.block();
        m_Signal();
        m_Connection.unblock()
    };

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<SignalT> > m_Signal;
    boost::signals::connection m_Connection;
};

template<class SignalT>
struct SlotBase<1, SignalT>
{
    // as above, except for operator()
    // ...

    void operator()(typename SignalT::arg1_type arg1)
    {
        m_Connection.block();
        m_Signal(arg1);
        m_Connection.unblock();
    };
};

template<class SignalT>
struct SlotBase<2, SignalT>
{
    // as above, except for operator()
    // ...

    void operator()(typename SignalT::arg1_type arg1, typename SignalT::arg2_type arg2)
    {
        m_Connection.block();
        m_Signal(arg1, arg2);
        m_Connection.unblock()
    };
};

// repeat for other arities
// ...

template<class SignalT>
class SlotObject : public SlotBase<SignalT::arity, SignalT>
{
    typedef SlotBase<SignalT::arity, SignalT> BaseType;

public:
    Slot(boost::shared_ptr<SignalT>S, 
         typename SignalT::slot_function_type F
    ) : BaseType(S, F)
    {}
};
```

**2)** If you are willing to give up a bit of syntax nicety for the users of SlotObject, other things are possible. One is to wrap the call to the signal using the technique shown in boost::shared_ptr documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#wrapper), ie, your Call() method would block the m_connection, and return a shared_ptr to m_signal having a custom deleter that unblocks m_connection.

Sadly, this does not give a nice syntax to the caller. It would look like:

```
SlotObject<signal<void(int, float)> > s = ...;
s.Call()->operator()(1, 1.234);
```

**3)** Another alternative is to ask the user to package the arguments in a tuple (I'm using a [boost::fusion::vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html) below) at the call site, and use [boost::fusion:::fused](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/functional/adapters/fused.html) to unpack them and call the signal.

```
#include <boost/function_types/parameter_types.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/fused.hpp>
#include <boost/signal.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

// Metafunction to extract the Signature template parameter
// from a boost::signal instantiation
// For example, SignatureOf<signal<void(int, float)>::type 
// is "void(int, float)"
template<class SignalT>
struct SignatureOf;

template<
    typename Signature, typename Combiner, typename Group,
    typename GroupCompare, typename SlotFunction
>
struct SignatureOf<
    boost::signal<Signature, Combiner, Group, GroupCompare, SlotFunction>
>
{
    typedef Signature type;
};

// The SlotObject    
template<class SignalT>
class SlotObject
{
public:
    typedef typename SignatureOf<SignalT>::type SignatureType;

    // Defines the "packed" parameters type corresponding
    // to the slot's signature
    // For example, for a SignalT of boost::signal<void(int, float)>
    // ArgsType is "boost::fusion::vector<int, float>"
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<
        typename boost::function_types::parameter_types<SignatureType>::type
    >::type ArgsType;

    void Call(ArgsType P)
    {
        m_Connection.block();
        boost::fusion::fused<SignalT&> f(*m_Signal);
        f(P);
        m_Connection.unblock();
    }

    //...
};
```

This would be used as:

```
typedef SlotObject<boost::signal<void(int, float)> > SlotType;
SlotType s = ...;
s.Call(SlotType::ArgsType(1, "foo"));
```